# SQLite ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have used this code in my program:

```
def insert(self, table, params):
  keys = ', '.join(params.keys())
  values = params.values()

  query = f"INSERT INTO songs ({keys}) VALUES (?, ?);" 
  print(keys)
  print(query)
  print(values)

  self.cur.execute(query , values)
  self.conn.commit()

  return self.cur.lastrowid
```

Which prints

```
name, filehash
INSERT INTO songs (name, filehash) VALUES (?, ?);
dict_values(['testaudio8.mp3', 
'BA614A989B7BCF44E38D00EEFFE96F2D8BD6677D'])
```

but returns the error:

```
self.cur.execute(query , values)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

I want to insert the values from dict_values into the question marks but I get the error. Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you include the entire code is easier to help. Maybe `query = f"INSERT INTO songs ({keys}) VALUES (?, ?);", ( 
  print(keys),
  print(query),
  print(values))`

Comment: instead of using a list of values and passing them to the 'self.cur.execute(query, values)' you should use a tuple.

Comment: The only reason i put print was to let everyone know what the values of each variable were. Using a tuple would lead to a ValueError: parameters must be str. Basically what I'm saying is ignore the print, I just want to insert the dict_values where the question marks are.

Answer (score 5):

what you need to do is

```
# skip a few connect code etc 
cur = con.cursor 

values = ("nameToInsert", "fileHash") # <-- Tuple 

cur.execute("INSERT INTO songs (name, filehash) VALUES (?, ?)", values)
```

Also if you have just one value, you need to pass it like so:

```
value = ("onlyValue", ) # see the ,
```

Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: `(value)` is just `value` while `(value, )` is a tuple.  This is how Python syntax is designed.  `print(type((1)), type((1, )))` prints `<class 'int'> <class 'tuple'>`.  I forgot this.  Thanks for the answer; the last bit helped me.

Comment: they said the `python` is easy to use, then a tube with one value require `,` , ohhhh

Answer (score 0):

Store keys, values in tuple

```
def insert(self, table, params):
  keys = tuple((params.keys())
  values = tuple(params.values())

  query = f"INSERT INTO songs ({keys}) VALUES (?, ?);" 
  print(keys)
  print(query)
  print(values)

  self.cur.execute(query , values)
  self.conn.commit()

  return self.cur.lastrowid
```